# How to recompute the thread numbers of comments?

Tags: comments

My articles currently have a text field *Note*, but I would like to get rid of it. Instead, I want these notes to be added as a comment on the article. Therefore, I have created a [Rule](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) with the following logic: if the article has a non-empty field *Note*, then create a new comment with a body equal to *Note*, set the article's author as the comment's author and set the comment's creation date as the article's creation date; also remove the text inside *Note*.

That works fine. However, the new comment shows up last in the comment list, instead of first. Apparently, Drupal does not order comments based on their creation date, but computes a *thread* value and uses this for ordering. Therefore, I am wondering whether one can recompute these threads (based on the comments' creation dates) after all *Note* fields have been converted into comments. All comments on my site have a node as their parent, because replying on other comments is currently disabled.

I am aware of the following alternative approach: create a [View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) with all the article's comments and order them on their creation date; use this View instead of the default comments list. However, creating yet another View seems to overcomplicate things.